# Loading pickle error : TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am making a document classifier and here is my code:

```
import os
import io
import numpy 
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, 
TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

def readFiles(path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

        inBody = False
        lines = []
        f = io.open(path, 'r', encoding='latin1')
        for line in f:
            if inBody:
                lines.append(line)
            elif line == '\n':
                inBody = True
        f.close()
        message = '\n'.join(lines)
        yield path, message


def dataFrameFromDirectory(path, classification):
    rows = []
    index = []
    for filename, message in readFiles(path):
    rows.append({'resume': message, 'class': classification})
    index.append(filename)

return DataFrame(rows, index=index)

data = DataFrame({'resume': [], 'class': []})

data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory(r'<path>', 'Yes'))
data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory(r'<path>', 'No'))
```

Then I split the data, and used Tfidf Vectorizer:

```
tf=TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
data_traintf=tf.fit_transform(data_train)
mnb=MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(data_traintf,class_train)
```

After training and testing, I saved my classifier as a pickle file:

```
import pickle

with open(r'clf.pkl','wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(mnb,f)
```

But when I load it again and try to use the classifier, I get `TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted` error. So I tried using pipeline and saved my vectorizer as well :

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

classifier=Pipeline([('tfidf',tf),('multiNB',mnb)])

with open(r'clf_1.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(classifier,f)
```

But still I get the same error. What might be going wrong?

EDIT: The pickle file was stored successfully and on the other end, I loaded the file:

```
import pickle

with open(r'clf_1.pkl','rb') as f:
    clf=pickle.load(f)
```

And created a test data frame. When I do `test_tf=tf.fit(test['resume'])` it works fine but `pred=clf.predict(test_tf)` gives error `TypeError: 'TfidfVectorizer' object is not iterable`

Do I need to loop through the data frame that has around 15 objects?

Comment: No, no need to loop through dataframe. But you are using wrong object. In the line `test_tf=tf.fit(test['resume'])` test_tf is not the transformed data, but the tf object. You need to call `test_tf=tf.transform(test['resume'])`. And I would advise you not to `fit()` the tf on test data. It should be fitted on train data and only call transform on test data.

Comment: Also, please clean up the question. The current code and post is hard to read. If you have tried two different things to solve the issue, please post the complete code for first choice, the error and then complete code for second one.